# Graphemes and symbols

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between 'graphemes' and 'symbols'? When I sreached it up, this is what came up: A grapheme is a written symbol of a phoneme.
I am positive that the very utility of a symbol is to represent a sound in a language. So what exactly is a grapheme and how is different from a symbol?

Comment: A and _A_ are two allographs of a single grapheme. Are they the same symbol or not? Your choice.

Comment: A symbol can represent an idea.  @      You might see the word *ideograph* used of graphemes that have ideational content.

Comment: Depending on how precisely you wish to speak of things, phonemes and "sounds" may or may not be the same.  A phoneme may be associated with more than one sound or "phone", and these sounds would be called allophones of the phoneme.

Comment: @TRomano Okay, so I can take it as graphemes and ideographs are part of the... well, a higher set, symbols?

Comment: Visual symbols. None of them are English, or even language. They're technology, like gearshift patterns.